# Intercept onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, options-menu

I have a top level TabHost that implements the onCreateOptionsMenu method. And I want sub-activities (those within the tabs) to be able to intercept the options menu via onOptionsItemSelected. Like for example, in the options menu I have an item called, "Edit Note" and in one tab there is a ListView with a list of all the notes. I want the "Edit Note" item to be able to be viewed throughout the application, but the top level TabActivity doesn't know information such as title or id of the note.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the tabs, and have the parent call down to the active child in the OnOptionsItemSelected to give it the chance to handle it first.